# VBA ActiveSheet.Cells behaving unexpectedly

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I'm working on a VBA word script that reads in some names and relevant info from an excel sheet, performs some computations to organize them correctly, and then pastes them into the word doc. This went well until I decided to make a function that would move a cell with the value "Anonymous" to the top of a range. For some reason, this isn't happening, and it appears to be because the .Cells method isn't always referring to the cell it was called on.

As the script itself is fairly long, I won't post the entire thing here. However, the relevant parts are a For loop in the main sub which deals with cells with the value "Anonymous"

```
 For curCol = 7 To 15
  lastRow = appXL.Cells(appXL.Rows.Count, curCol).End(xlUp).Row
  For curRow = 1 To lastRow
   Dim curCell As excel.Range
   Set curCell = appXL.Cells(curRow, curCol)
   Dim anonCount As Integer
   anonCount = 0
   If curCell.Value = "Anonymous" Or curCell.Value = "Anonymous*" Then
    If anonCount < 1 Then
     anonCount = anonCount + 1
     MoveAnon (curRow), (curCol), (lastRow)
    Else
     anonCount = anonCount + 1
     curCell.Value = curCell.Value + " (" + CStr(anonCount) + ")"
     MoveAnon (curRow), (curCol), (lastRow)
    End If
   End If
  Next curRow
 Next curCol
```

You'll notice that within this loop is a call to a subroutine "MoveAnon" which is

```
Sub MoveAnon(currentRow As Integer, currentCol As Integer, thelastRow As Integer)
 Dim text As String
 Debug.Print ("Using Row: " + CStr(currentRow) + ", Column: " + CStr(currentCol) + ", Last Row: " + CStr(thelastRow))
 text = excel.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol)
 Debug.Print ("Hit On: " & excel.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol))

 If currentRow > 1 Then
  excel.Application.ActiveSheet.Range(excel.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, currentCol).Address, excel.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow - 1, currentCol).Address).Cut excel.Application.ActiveSheet.Range(excel.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, currentCol).Address)
  excel.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, currentCol).Value = text
 End If
End Sub
```

Through testing and with Deubg.Print, I've noticed that the line `Debug.Print ("Hit On: " & excel.Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, currentCol))` refers to all manner of different cells then the one on which it was called. For example, whenever I use Cells(6, 15), I get a value from a cell that is actually on row 42, column 15. The difference between the cell its called on and the cell it returns is not always the same (I've seen -7, +36, and 0), but it is always in the correct column.

Does anyone have any idea as to what my cause this behavior to arise? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Assuming your variable has appropriate scope, you should be using `appXL` not `excel.application`

Comment: You set `anonCount = 0` inside the inner loop so it's not clear how the value could ever be >0 to trigger the `Else` block?  What exactly is `appXL` ?  It looks from the name like an Excel Application object, but you use it like a worksheet...

Comment: To avoid this whole spaghetti entirely, you could pass a `Range` object instead of a row & column and then use `Range.Parent` to ensure you are referencing the correct application & worksheet. You can also use `Range.Resize` to simplify that long line.

Answer (score 0):

It's much faster to read the whole range into an array, then populate another array of the same size with the "Anonymous*" at the top, and replace the range values using the second array.

Eg.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim curCol As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    For curCol = 7 To 15
        MoveAnon ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, curCol), _
                          ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, curCol).End(xlUp))
    Next curCol

End Sub

'Given a (single-column) range, move all values like "Anonymous*"
'  to the top of the range
Sub MoveAnon(rng As Range)
    Const TXT As String = "Anonymous*"
    Dim v, i As Long, num As Long
    Dim arrIn, arrOut, nA As Long, nX As Long
    
    num = Application.CountIf(rng, TXT)                         'how many to float up
    If num = 0 Then Exit Sub                                    'nothing to do here?
    arrIn = rng.Value                                           'read to array
    ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn, 1), 1 To UBound(arrIn, 2))  'size output array
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrIn, 1)      'loop the input array
        v = arrIn(i, 1)
        If v Like TXT Then
            nA = nA + 1
            arrOut(nA, 1) = v          '"Anonymous*" goes at the top
        Else
            nX = nX + 1
            arrOut(num + nX, 1) = v    'everything else goes below
        End If
    Next i
    rng.Value = arrOut                 'replace using the shuffled array
End Sub
```